# Безуспешное подключение к базе linux (ora 12162)

Tags: oracle11g, unix-odbc

Пробую подключиться к Oracle 11g в Linux
Через Windows ODBC тестовое подключение успешно
В Linux пробую `sqlplus / as sysdba` (либо через созданного пользователя - ошибка таже)

```
ORA-12162 TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

Как устанавливал:
Скачал zip: oracle instant client linux x86-64

- Basic Package
- SDK Package
- SQL*PLUS

И все розархивировал по пути `/opt/oracle`
После в терминале:

```
export PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_8:$PATH;
ORACLE_SID=XE; 
export $ORACLE_SID;

echo $ORACLE_HOME
> /usr/lib/oracle/21.8/client64
----------------------------
sqlplus / as sysdba
ORA-12162 TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

`/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_8/network/admin`

> listener.ora

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.122.205)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

> tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.122.205)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

ip, port, sid - корректны

Comment: А у вас БД на этом же сервере? sqlplus / as sysdba допустимо только для локальной установки инстанса Oracle

Comment: @SwaD, База на виртуалке. Я так же пробовал подключаться через созданного пользователя(в linux ошибка та же, а в windows успешен тестовый коннект)